# Synchronous processing works with Batch Processing?

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-studio, synchronous

I do have bunch of xml files say hundreds in my source directory. I have made my flow processing strategy to be **synchronous** to execute only 1 xml file at a time as performance 
is not much priority to me. But i do have batch processing in my flow. So what i under stand is flow thread is creating a **child thread** to execute my Batch processing and control moves forward. My whole transformation code lies in batch processing which takes 30secs to execute a xml. So nothing much logic in my main flow except file inbound EP and batch execute component(to trigger batch job). So file inbound endpoint is keep on pollingfiles and whole bunch xmls getting picked in very less time make my mule memory out and unexpected behavior occurs. 
Came to know fork-join pattern very late and it may or not fit into my req.

So is there any configuration to make my batch process completely and
execute and pick the next files. Help me out. I already made processing strategy synchronous!!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you in this case just adjust the polling frequency at the file inbound endpoint?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/file-connector

Polling Frequency
(Applies to inbound File endpoints only.)

Specify how often the endpoint should check for incoming messages. The default value is 1000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Set `maxThreadsActive` and `maxBufferSize`

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/tuning-performance#calculating-threads